# Compiling files with laravel + elixir

Tags: css, laravel, coffeescript, sass, laravel-elixir

I am taking over a laravel project that uses elixir to compile various sass, coffeescript, and javascript files:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('main.scss')
        .coffee(['methods.coffee', 'details.coffee', 'cars.coffee', 'context-menu.coffee', 'content.coffee', 'projects.coffee', 'main.coffee'])
        .styles(['main.css'], 'public/css/all.css', 'public/css')
        .scripts(['app.js'], 'public/js/all.js', 'public/js')
        .version(['css/all.css', 'js/all.js']);
});
```

My questions:

What is the destination of the files below after they are compiled?

`.coffee(['methods.coffee', 'details.coffee', 'cars.coffee', 'context-menu.coffee', 'content.coffee', 'projects.coffee', 'main.coffee'])`

Does the line below compile the `app.js` file as `all.js` and store it in `public/js`?

`.scripts(['app.js'], 'public/js/all.js', 'public/js')`

Similarly, does the line below compile the `main.css` file as `all.css` and store it in `public/css`?

`.styles(['main.css'], 'public/css/all.css', 'public/css')`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the task will place the compiled in:

- sass   = public/css/app.css
- coffee = public/js/app.js
- scripts= public/js/all.js
- styles = public/css/all.css

**UPDATE**

To change the output path just pass a second argument to the method

e.g.

```
mix.styles([
    'bundle.css'
], 'public/css/aloha');
```

Comment: Thanks - so to confirm, `.styles(['main.css'], 'public/css/all.css', 'public/css')` places changes `main.css` to `all.css` and places it in `public/css` correct?

Comment: The **second argument** is the **base output path** (public/css/all.css) and the **third argument** is the **base source path** (public/css)